# Highcharts custom scaling on y axis - mix of linear and logarithmic

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, highcharts

I am trying to use a logarithmic scale on my chart like below:

[image]

However, the outbound data is much lower than the inbound data. This doesnt show properly in the graph and makes it look like there is actually more outbound data than inbound.

I would like to have a linear scale upto the max value of the y axis (136) and some additional offest so basically upto 150 it should display linear scale and from there upto 600 (which shows the max capacity marker) to be logarithmic. Is this at all possible with Highcharts? Maybe the best function to use would be tickPositioner http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner.

The final desired result should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Does data ever get to 400 or 600? If not, just use linear scale. If it does or you want to have log you need to use log. You cannot mix scales on a single axis. Your first graph looks fine to me. "graph and makes it look like there is actually more outbound data than inbound" - does not appear that way to me. Indbound is always greater it looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is certainly a messy solution, but you could composite two graphs together:

[image]

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B2a6R/).

```
$(function () {
        $('#containerBot').highcharts({
            chart: {marginTop: 1},
            title: {margin: 0, text: ''},
            yAxis: {max: 100},
            exporting: {enabled: false},
            series: [{
                name: 'One',
                data: [70.0, 60.9, 90.5, 140.5, 180.2, 210.5, 205.2, 260.5, 230.3, 180.3, 130.9, 90.6]
            }, {
                name: 'Two',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 50.7, 110.3, 170.0, 220.0, 240.8, 204.1, 200.1, 140.1, 80.6, 20.5]
            }]
        });
        $('#containerTop').highcharts({
            chart: {marginBottom: -1},
            title: {text: 'My Chart'},
            yAxis: {min: 100},
            xAxis: {labels: {enabled: false}},
            legend: {enabled: false},
            exporting: {enabled: false},
            credits: {enabled: false},
            series: [{
                name: 'One',
                data: [70.0, 60.9, 90.5, 140.5, 180.2, 210.5, 205.2, 260.5, 230.3, 180.3, 130.9, 90.6]
            }, {
                name: 'Two',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 50.7, 110.3, 170.0, 220.0, 240.8, 204.1, 200.1, 140.1, 80.6, 20.5]
            }]
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I dont understand your solution...can you please elaborate?

Comment: @JCrow, Highcharts does not allow you to change the "step" scaling on a single chart.  This code composites two charts together, the bottom "steps" by increments of 25, the top "steps" by increments of 100.